# How parse XML to get one tag and save another tag inside

Tags: php, xml, dom

I use [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)
extension of PHP5.3 to parse some xml document with <title> tag like this:

**<title>some text <word>keyword</word> some text</title>**

I want get result from tag <title> with certain tags inside it (i want know keywords that's why i want save tag <word> inside tag <title>). Result in this case must be something like this:

**some text [word]keyword[/word] some text**

I do some code:

`$title=$doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;`

$title must contain some result. But I get only text without any tags inside it and I don't know now where keywords is.

**some text keyword some text**

I don't know how to save tag <word>!
How could I get result like **some text [word]keyword[/word] some text** from DOM extension?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you viewing the `$title` via browser? remember that your browser will try to render tags and skip unknown ones. Try doing `echo  htmlentities($title)` to force displaying the tags as-is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything + the tags themselves, there's always `saveXML`:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php

You pass the node you want and it gives you a string back, though the `<title>` start and end tags will be included. Also it will include attributes as well.

Comment: $parse_xml->saveXML($doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0));