# How to get content of <tagname> that contains other embedded XML tag in Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, sax

I have an XML document that has HTML tags included:

```
<chapter>
      <h1>title of content</h1>
      <p> my paragraph ... </p>
 </chapter>
```

I need to get the content of `<chapter>` tag and my output will be:

```
      <h1>title of content</h1>
      <p> my paragraph ... </p>
```

My question is similar to this post: [How parse XML to get one tag and save another tag inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953295/how-parse-xml-to-get-one-tag-and-save-another-tag-inside)

But I need to implement it in Java using SAX or DOM or ...?

I found a soluton using SAX in this post: [SAX Parser : Retrieving HTML tags from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602359/sax-parser-retrieving-html-tags-from-xml/7623130#7623130) but it's very buggy and doesn't work with large amounts of XML data.

## Updated:

My SAX implementation:
In some situation it throw exception: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -4029

```
public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private boolean tagFlag = false;

private char[] temp;
String insideTag;
private int startPosition;
private int endPosition;
private String tag;

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {


    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
        tagFlag = true;
    }

}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {

        insideTag = new String(temp, startPosition, endPosition - startPosition);
        tagFlag = false;
    }

}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    temp = ch;
    if (tagFlag) {
        startPosition = start;
        tagFlag = false;
    }
    endPosition = start + length;
}

public String getInsideTag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
    return insideTag;
}

}
```

## Update 2: (Using StringBuilder)

I have accumulated characters by StringBuilder in this way:

```
public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private boolean tagFlag = false;

private char[] temp;
String insideTag;
private String tag;
private StringBuilder builder;

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        tagFlag = true;
    }

}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
        insideTag = builder.toString();
        tagFlag = false;
    }
}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if (tagFlag) {
        builder.append(ch, start, length);
    }
}

public String getInsideTag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
    return insideTag;
}

}
```

But `builder.append(ch, start, length);` doesn't append Start tag like`<EmbeddedTag atr="...">` and `</EmbeddedTag>` in the Buffer. This Code print Output:

```
      title of content
      my paragraph ...
```

Instead of expected output:

```
      <h1>title of content</h1>
      <p> my paragraph ... </p>
```

## Update 3:

Finally I have implemented the parser handler:

```
 public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private boolean tagFlag = false;
private String insideTag;
private String tag;
private StringBuilder builder;

public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        tagFlag = true;
    }

    if (tagFlag) {
        builder.append("<" + qName);
         for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
         builder.append(" " + attributes.getLocalName(i) + "=\"" +
         attributes.getValue(i) + "\"");
         }
         builder.append(">");
    }
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    if (tagFlag) {
        builder.append("</" + qName + ">");
    }

    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase(tag)) {
        insideTag = builder.toString();                     
        tagFlag = false;
    }
    System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

}

public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    temp = ch;

    if (tagFlag) {
        builder.append(ch, start, length);
    }
}

public String getInsideTag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
    return insideTag;
}

}
```

Comment: You need to better define the input XML and specifically as possible the output desired as your post is not clear on this at all. It appears that you want some tags to remain, but others not to.  Also if the XML is very large, then DOM may not be feasible since DOM requires that the whole document model be loaded before analysis is performed. The other options are SAX and StAX.

Comment: Thanks for editing my bad writing. Yes I need to get content of <chapter> tag. In have updated my post with my SAX implementation but it doesn't work in some situation. Could you help me with my updated question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you try to remember the start and end positions of the string passed to you via the `characters` method. What you see in the exception thrown is the result of an inside tag that starts near the end of a character buffer and ends near the beginning of the next character buffer.

With sax you need to copy the characters when they are offered or the temporary buffer they occupy might be cleared when you need them.

Your best bet is not to remember the positions in the buffers, but to create a new `StringBuilder` in `startElement` and add the characters to that, then get the complete string out the builder in `endElement`.

Comment: I have changed my code by adding character to StringBuilder, But The problem is that in characters() callback I havent access to start of tagname and end of tagname! So I have to change StringBuilder parameters like this: handler.append(ch, start - startTag.length, length + endTag.length) .how should I do this?

Comment: You could add the opening and closing tags in the start- and endElement methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/), I've used it years ago, version 1.5 and it were simply to create mapping for xml like you. Just simple [article](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364926/Using-The-Digester-Component) how to use Digester, but it is for version 1.5 and currently there is 3.0 I think last version contains a lot of new features ...